# why I cannot assign real[0] to address of x

Tags: c

When i change the `char*` to `char**` code works but I cannot understand why I cannot assign `real[0]` to an address.

When i allocate `10*sizeof(char)` memory, does it not mean that I can use `real[0]` to `real[9]`?

I understand that `char** real` - after using with as below

```
char** real = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
```

This solves the problem. It allocates 10 `char*` and because of this I can assign the address of `x` and `y` and for the same reason in the case of `char*` I cannot assign the address because it is just for the char characters?

Finally, I am wondering when I can use `real[0]`, `real[1]` etc.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(){

    char* real = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    char x = 'a';
    char y = 'b';

    real[0] = &x;
    real[1] = &y;

    printf("%c %c\n",x,y);
    printf("%x\n",real[0]);
    printf("%x\n",real[1]);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(&x));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(&y));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've defined `real[0]` and `real[1]` to be characters, not pointers. You could say `real[0] = x` instead of `real[0] = &x`

Comment: Assuming that you could do that, what would it even mean? What do you *want* it to mean?

Comment: Thank you! But i just want to be sure whether x can be some part of array which is storing bytes?

Comment: Yes. But you would still need to declare `real` as `char **`, then let's say `x` is `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` (which is a `char *`) then you can have `real[0] = x;` as an assignment.

Comment: i am trying to assign an adress of one byte to a pointer. But i need to read data from a file including 512 bytes.

Comment: you, i understand i can use real[0], real[1] etc. since if we assign data to a pointer, i can reach inside of pointer by using array. Am i right? Because i thought before if i use char*, i can not reach real[0], real[1]. Sorry for the ambiguity!

Comment: If you use `char *` you can reach `real[0]` etc, but they will be `char`s. You can for example store the VALUE of x to it, but not the ADDRESS of x.

Answer (score 2):

`real` is a `char*` and hence `real[0]` is a `char`. You can do `real[0] = x;`. Also, if you really want to hold a pointer to `x`, you need to make `real` a `char**` and handle allocation accordingly.

Comment: real [0] is a char that it shows what i assign for the pointer right? if char* real; char x[5] = "life"  real[0] = x means real[0] = 'l' ?

Comment: Are you trying to print the address of `x`? If so, you can directly do `printf("%x\n", &x);` The range of a pointer depends on your machine's word-size, but will almost surely not fit in `char`.

Answer (score 2):

`&x` is a pointer to a char.

Since `real` is a `char *` (aka a pointer to a char), `real[0]` is a char, NOT a pointer to a char. (`real[0]` is the same as `*(real+0)` which means that the pointer will be dereferenced to get a char.)

If you want to store `&x` in `real`, you need to declare it as a `char **`, which means that it is a pointer to a pointer to a char. Then, when you dereference it, you will get a pointer to a char, which is what `&x` is.

It is true that you can use `real[0]` to `real[9]`, but note that if you declare `real` as `char **` then `real[0]` to `real[9]` will all be pointers to char (or addresses of char). It may be useful if you want to change their values in an external function.

Comment: thanks! i think i got the point. For my case, i ll stuck with the char*. Because i just want to read data from a file to a pointer(buffer) and want to compare the first 4 bytes with another 4 bytes. when i read from the file byte by byte, i think every byte will be assigned to real[0], real[1]... real[3]. i ll go with char*.